# Address Registration/ permit in Germany?

Tags: germany, resident-permit

I am an EU citizen starting a course with a German Uni in 3 weeks. As the time draws closer a few worries have surfaced and I am now stressing, so if someone could read my situation and give helpful advice or feedback it would be  well appreciated.

Situation: In short I was an Aupair in Hamburg for a year and of course, had a residence permit to live there with the host family. Then I decided I wanted to study here (Germany) thus both applying and being accepted to my desired course shortly after. So as one would, I began looking for a WG.I Found a great WG and began paying rent to secure it even though i knew i wouldnt be able to move in fully for another 3/4 months. Here is where i worry: I am in my home country now and realised i never got a residence permit or registered my new Address. Its been over three months and ive been paying rent yet i havent signed a lease ( I will do that when i return in 3 weeks)

Any Advice??

I though perhaps when i return i can date the lease on the day i return so i can register everything and get a permit in perfect time, after all it states when i 'MOVE IN' and an official move in would be the signing of the lease, right? not the date from first rent payment.

So in conclusion, someone help me. ich brauche dringend hilfe und Hinweise. Danke

Comment: In Germany, one is obliged to register himself at the place where **he/she lives** (start of the rental contract does not matter) within 2 weeks. If one actually has not started living there, technically one should yet not be registered there as well. Theoretically, one may need to deregister from previous address (if one does not live anymore by host family), however, if the host family is fine with the fact considering that one still "lives" by them while just travelling to the home country, I do not see any issue here. See related answer: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/11147/13223